# How do I move my question from one site to another?

Tags: support, specific-question, migration

I asked a question on Stack Overflow, [Is there a benefit for programmers to know how to build a PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356939/is-there-a-benefit-for-programmers-to-know-how-to-build-a-pc), which was then closed as not programming related. I then realized that Super User would be a better place for the question.

The issue is that the question is now simply closed whereas I would like the ability to "Send to Super User" or something like that.

Is this possible?

Comment: If it belongs to SU, the mods will move it. Post a link!

Comment: Already voted to re-open.  Better suited to SO than the other sites in my opinion.

Comment: I think that question might have been closed because it wasn't Community Wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy enough to re-open and move - but at the moment it is a big programmer-heavy ("Is there a benefit for programmers to know how to build a PC").

Two options:

- edit it to make it SU-friendly, and then ask for it to be re-opened and moved
- ask the question you **really** want to ask, but on SU (less programmer stuff)

I'd be tempted to just do the second; i.e. leave the old one (or delete it), and ask a fresh question on SU.

Answer (score 1):

One close option is to migrate to anothersute. You can flag your post for moderator attention and they can reopen the question and then migrate it to the correct site.

Comment: this seems quite manual.. i would have thought a simple link could trigger this

Comment: @oo: Nope. If you have >250 rep, you can vote to migrate your question, but you need 4 other folks to say, "YES WE CAN" before it actually gets migrated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to see this question re-opened at SO, though. It is a valid question since it's something many programmers are wondering about, but never really ask.

Comment: Actually, some of them **do** ask. For instance, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514/how-much-should-a-software-guy-or-software-gal-know-about-hardware
and also here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995981/is-it-essential-to-understand-computers-to-be-a-good-programmer